# Android - How to customize rounding value?

Tags: java, android, rounding

Hi i really bad at rounding. i am trying to round up a value to the rounding of my country currency.

The rounding example will be :

`1.01 > 1.00

    1.02 > 1.00

    1.03 > 1.05

    1.04 > 1.05

    1.06 > 1.05

    1.07 > 1.05

    1.08 > 1.10

    1.09 > 1.10`

How can i do this kind of rounding? Thanks a lot .

Comment: Side comment: You don't say what type your number is.  Everyone is assuming it's `double`.  But it's not recommended to use `float` or `double` when dealing with currency, because those do not represent most numbers exactly.  Look into [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to give you the correct mappings - you may need to tweak it when you decide exactly where the cutoffs are.

```
public void test() {
  double [] tests = new double[] {1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9};
  for ( double d : tests) {
    System.out.println("    "+d + " -> "+round(d, .05, 0.5));
  }
}

double round(double d, double fraction, double bias) {
  return Math.floor(d / fraction + bias) * fraction;
}
```

This prints:

```
1.01 -> 1.0
1.02 -> 1.0
1.03 -> 1.05
1.04 -> 1.05
1.05 -> 1.05
1.06 -> 1.05
1.07 -> 1.05
1.08 -> 1.1
1.09 -> 1.1
```

Comment: sorry i edited my question, now should be the correct question. THanks

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're rounding by 0.05 = 1/20th. So the following works:

```
public static double roundCurrency( double value ) {
    return Math.round(value * 20.0 ) / 20.0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double roundedvalue= Math.round( YourValue* 100.0 ) / 100.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double roundedvalue= Math.round( YourValue* 2.0 ) / 2.0;
```

Comment: Note to anyone reading this: This answer was correct before the questioner edited the question and changed the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

`Math.round` lets you round a number to the nearest integer.  It looks like you're trying to round to the nearest multiple of 0.5.  The general way to solve problems like that is

```
roundedValue = Math.round (X / M) * M;
```

to round to the nearest multiple of `M`.  So in your case that would be

```
roundedValue = Math.round (X / 0.5) * 0.5;
```

which is the same as

```
roundedValue = Math.round (X * 2.0) / 2.0;
```

Similarly, if you wanted to round something to the nearest multiple of, say, 0.01, one of these would work:

```
roundedValue = Math.round (X / 0.01) * 0.01;
roundedValue = Math.round (X * 100.0) / 100.0;
```

**EDIT:** It looks like you've changed your question, so what I said earlier about rounding to the nearest multiple of 0.5 isn't correct any more, and now you're rounding to the nearest multiple of 0.05.  Anyway, the general method I've discussed still works.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html documentation on the Math Class. It lets you perform operations such as `Math.round(double x)` and
`Math.ceil(double x)` and `Math.floor(double x)` . You can use these in combination with an if else statement such as

```
double value = 1.6;

String valueToString = Double.toString(value);
String [] numbers = valueToString.split(".");
String decimalNums = numbers[1];
int decimal = Integer.parseInt(decimalNums);

if(decimal > 0 && decimal < 5){
   decimal =  Math.floor(decimal);
}else if(decimal >= 5 && decimal < 8){
   decimal = 5;
}else{
   decimal = Math.ceil(decimal);
}
```

This will only work for values that have one decimal place. But its a start. Hope it helps a little.